# "Save operation failed invalid MIME part type" in Lightswitch HTML Client

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch, lightswitch-2012

When trying to save a record in VS Lightswitch HTML Client I get this error pop up.

"Save operation failed invalid MIME part type"

It does it in the HTML Client but I don't know if it's exclusive to that.

This will happen even if i create a new project, add one table with one field and one screen to add a record so has nothing to do with complexity.

Funny thing is that the record saves but doesn't show up until the page has been reloaded. (Refreshing hangs, you have to hit the url again.)

I'm using VS2012 Premium with update 2. There are no attached datasources, it's just using the basic SQL Express Lightswitch generated data.

Answer (score 0):

This problem turned out to be only in Opera!